# Making a daily checklist for vedanta karma and upasana yoga requirements

Tags: karma, yoga

I have tried to develop a daily checklist based on my role as a sannyasa and a jnana marga to moksa. Please assist me if you find something I am lacking to progress from a mumuksu to a jijnasu.
- deva yajna
- pitr yajna
- Brahma yajna
- manusya yajna
- bhuta yajna
- concentration meditation
- expansion meditation
- value meditation
- relaxation meditation
- accept
- no comparing
- humility
- devotion

any comments on what I may be overlooking would be highly appreciated. namaskar.